# Build artifact missing from new release's combo, creating release directly from retained build causes VS402962

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We're using on-prem AzureDevopsServer2019, with on-prem build agents. I'm trying to create a new release, which consists of 3 artifacts.

The (retained) build artifact I want doesn't show in the available builds comboboxes of the new release (this has happened on more than one artifact)

Alternatively, when I try and create a release directly from the retained build, I scroll through my many historic builds, find the "missing" build, click release, populate the other artifacts in the new release, then when I click "Create" get:

> "VS402962: No artifact version ID is specified corresponding to
> artifact source 'MyBuild'. Specify a valid value and try again

Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build artifact missing from new release's combo, creating release directly from retained build causes VS402962

You should check if you specify the `projectname` for the `alias`, it should be the source alias. Since you want to use the build artifacts, the “alias” variable should be your build definition name not your project name.

If above not work for you, try to create a new build pipeline, there is a ticket report this issue, but there is no one effective solution. This is an annoying issue in Azure DevOps:

[Unable to release ~20% of the pipeline builds to any release pipeline](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/699088/unable-to-release-20-of-the-pipeline-builds-to-any.html)

If you encounter this too, please reopen it and add your feedback and more useful information.